# How to show blocked portion of a sprite in different color

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-development

I would like to know how to do something as shown in the screenshot using SpriteKit. As a sprite moves around the map, the part that is covered by other sprites is showing in different color.

[image]

Please let me know how it is done. Thank you in advance.